# Roots of $PQ$ if $Q$ is irreducible + Condition on degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let say we have two polynomials of a integral domain $R[X]$. Let's call them $P$ and $Q$.
We suppose $\deg P + \deg Q = N$, with $N>1$ being an integer.
We also suppose that $Q$ is a second degree polynomial of the form $(X^2-m)$ , so that $Q$ is irreducible.
As $R[X]$ is integral , $\deg PQ=\deg P + \deg Q = N$.

Is there a way of knowing if $PQ$ has roots for $N$ fixed? I'm only interested about the result of existence.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Since $Q$ has no roots, $PQ$ has a root iff $P$ does.  Not sure what the degree has to do with anything.  Nor, for that matter, what role $Q$ is playing.